# How do I compress Object[][] in C#

Tags: c#, compression

I need to compress object[][] in C#. I can use Gzip comrepss- decompress a byte[] but how to do it in such cases ?

Comment: Which kinds of objects do you have in your array ? If they can be serialized, you can serialize them, and then GZip compress the result. If they cannot be serialized, there is no generic or standard way to perform a compression.

Comment: You need to provide more info.  What is the output of such a method?  What kind of objects are in that array?  Are they value types or reference types, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use binary serialization to turn it into a byte array which you'd then zip. Provided all the objects in the array are serializable, you can do the following

```
object[][] objects = new[] {new[] {"a"}};
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(File.OpenWrite("C:\\zipped.zip"), 
    CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    formatter.Serialize(gZipStream, objects);
}

//unzipping
using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(File.OpenRead("C:\\zipped.zip"), 
    CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    objects = (object[][])formatter.Deserialize(gZipStream);
    Console.WriteLine(objects[0][0]); //a
}
```

Comment: +1 And the process [/code] to deserialize would be? (For the sake of completeness)

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert your `object[][]` into a `byte[]`
2. Compress the `byte[]`

Step 1 is the hard part, and will require that all your objects are serializable, so that they can be converted into `byte[]`s.

The reason this is tricky is that the contents of an `object[]` are actually just memory references to various `object`s in memory, and those `object`s can likewise have references to other `object`s. Some can even reference specific system resources like I/O ports that have been allocated to them. It wouldn't make sense to send an object like this to a different computer, because that computer has not given the same resources to the object, right? So unless the classes have specifically indicated that they can be serialized and deserialized to a byte stream, you can't do anything with them.